# Sorting list of strings in lexicographic order

Tags: python, list, sorting, lexicographic

I want to print the words in lexicographic order. I thought `sorted()` arranges the words in this way. I have also tried `.sort()` which returns the same order. Or am I missing something with what lexicographic order really is?

Code:

```
a_list = ['Zrhregegrydb', 'cygzRFWDWBdvF']
for word in sorted(a_list):
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
# Zrhregegrydb
# cygzRFWDWBdvF
```

Desired Output:

```
# cygzRFWDWBdvF
# Zrhregegrydb
```

Comment: Do you want to sort lower-case letters before upper-case letters, or completely ignore the case?

Comment: Lexicographic order and case-insensitivity are seemingly independent but are in fact conflicting concepts. Letter casing is locale/culture-specific. Once you go there, you lose the concept of lexicographic order. Do you actually want a sort order based on the user's locale?

Answer (score 5):

By default, python already sorts strings in lexicographical order, but uppercase letters are all sorted before lowercase letters. If you want to sort strings and ignore case, then you can do

```
b_list = sorted(a_list, key=str.lower)
```

Comment: specifying `str.lower` directly as the key is faster than calling a lambda which calls `str.lower`. Even better, use [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold).

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point. It's less typing, too.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the ASCII value of upper-case letters is smaller than lower-case. If you want your sort to ignore case you can do this, for example:

```
for word in sorted(a_list, key=str.lower):
```

Comment: The problem here is that lower- and uppercase letters will be in arbitrary order. Example outputs: `['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']` or `['a', 'A', 'B', 'b']` (depends on input order).

Answer (score 3):

You are missing something. In the standard, Unicode order (starting with the old ASCII order), all upper-case English letters come before all lower-case letters. You can see that in [a table of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin).

If you want to ignore the case while sorting, as it seems you do, just temporarily convert all the letters to upper-case or to lower-case during the sort. Python allows you to do that in the `sorted` function with the `key` parameter, as you can see in other answers here (finished before I finished this answer).

Answer (score 2):

You could ignore the case when sorting:

```
sorted_list = sorted(a_list, key = lambda s : s.lower())
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to iterate using the indexes to see the right order.

Here is the code how you can do it.

```
a_list = ['Zrhregegrydb', 'cygzRFWDWBdvF']
a_list.sort(reverse=True)
for i in range(0, len(a_list)):
    print a_list[i]
```

Comment: And the loop from the OP is preferred to looping over `range()`.

Comment: I did and it worked perfectly I tested the code then given the answer can you check again

Comment: https://repl.it/@codeguru/TriangularNutritiousLicenses I get the output as `xyz` first then `abc` which is in reverse alphabetical order. This is not the OP's desired result.

Comment: If you want abc first just remove reverse=True and it will do the job I provided the code according to his requirement

Comment: Yes, your code works for the example given. However, your proposed solution does not work for other possible inputs. Removing `reverse=True` just gives the original code from the question which is not a valid solution, either.